# Disable TeXlipse automatic build but keep building the rest of the project

Tags: eclipse, tex

I have Java code and TeX documents in the same project. I use TeXlipse (because I like the editor's functions) but I don't want it to try to build my TeX docs every time the project builds automatically. The reason is that the configuration of my TeX document tree is complex, I use Makefiles to compile those documents, and don't want to configure TeXlipse to find all the right locations for the bib files, etc.  At the same time, I want the rest of the project (mostly Java code) to automatic build, as usual.

Is it possible to prevent TeXlipse to be part of the project building?  At the moment, every time I save a Java file, a get some pesky window "Question from an External Program" with some LaTeX question that keeps popping up.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oops -- I just found how to do it: Project > Properties > Builders: disable Latex Builder.